# Strange looking words using webkit transform rotate in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, webkit

I've trying to get some vertical text on a little test webpage after reading an article on how to do this.  In my CSS I have the following:

```
#navMenu li{
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
}
```

And the navMenu in my markup is:

```
<ul id="navMenu">
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>About</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
```

This works fine in FF 3.6, IE8(!) but in Chrome some of the words look distorted/fuzzy.  2 particular words that look 'odd' are: Contact and Portfolio.  Why would certain words be messed up but all others are okay?

I thought it was having a 'round' letter (c, o, q etc) at the end of the word so I did a little bit of testing (by no means exhaustive), I changed Portfolio to: Portfolix and Portfoliw which were okay but if I tried Portfoliq, Protfolie or Portfolit then it's distorted.

Any ideas as to why this happens and any ways to remedy it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome uses Windows GDI for text drawing on Windows. I'm guessing that to rotate, it will draw the horizontal text to a bitmap in memory and then rotate it and render it to the screen. Could be an issue with preserving the font smoothing or maybe [font hinting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font_hinting) is being done assuming the horizontal orientation then the transformation is applied; resulting in the pixel distortion. You may also be interested in [subpixel rendering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering).

Here's [a blog](http://blog.athe.la/2010/01/sub-pixel-rendering-hinting-in-chrome-is-inferior-to-that-of-firefox/) comparing subpixel rendering in chrome and firefox. [This](http://www.dria.org/wordpress/archives/2008/06/10/651/) is an older article about Firefox's font rendering.