# -webkit-transform CSS Properties Hose Font Rendering

Tags: safari, webkit, css, safari-extension

This question is pretty much the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2289844/strange-looking-words-using-webkit-transform-rotate-in-chrome) except that I'm seeing it exclusively in Safari on Mac (the only platform I need to care about). It's definitely CSS-related and I think I've narrowed it down to a few properties which seem to wreak havoc on the way text is rendered. They are:

```
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
-webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
-webkit-perspective: 2500;
```

As soon as I disable these (by prefixing them with an "x", e.g. `x-webkit-*`), the text renders fine. Enabling any *one* of them results in the borked text. Here are a couple of screenshots that may help visualize the difference.

http://s3.amazonaws.com/codaset/ticket/6404/665/good.png http://s3.amazonaws.com/codaset/ticket/6404/666/bad.png

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this or if/how it can be fixed? Google hasn't been terribly helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: +1 for "Hose" and good question to boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transforms in Safari are hardware-accelerated. It allows for much better speed, but the rendering doesn't follow the same pipeline, and some quality is lost. There's nothing you can do about it, except not use transforms. :/

Comment: Well, crap. That was the one answer I _didn't_ want to hear. :-) Is there anywhere else I can follow up on this for more info? I can't find squat on Google. Thanks.

Comment: @Rob Wilkerson: I'll try to search again. I remember animating a png, and during the animation its quality would be lowered, and that was because of the hardware acceleration. I don't remember where I found the info though.

Comment: In this case, it's not _during_ the animation. Just having those styles active--even when no transformations are active--degrades the quality.

Comment: I just got confirmation of this from an Apple employee in their dev forums--https://devforums.apple.com/message/271429#271429.

Comment: Screenshot of the Apple dev forums posted by Rob: http://imgur.com/MXSGDX8 (the forum is behind a login)

Answer (score 13):

I think this is actually possible to fix in later iOS revisions (I believe 3.2 & 4.0) by using `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased`. Note: The aliasing will still be different, but will look less awkward if it's animated.

Comment: Is it iOS-specific or will it help me on non-mobile OSes?

Comment: Another great but hard-to-find webkit fix. OP should mark this as the answer.

Comment: Works for me... better than other solutions e.g. setting an transform on the body tag to render the whole page in opengl mode.

Comment: YAAAAAAAY! Chrome didn't care but it looks great on my ipad here

Comment: *Please Stop "Fixing" Font Smoothing* http://www.usabilitypost.com/2012/11/05/stop-fixing-font-smoothing/

Answer (score 0):

Came across this issue today and had to use `transform: scale(1.1) translate3d(0,0,0);` (http://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/transforms-cause-font-smoothing-weirdness-in-webkit/) to get it working.