# Mac Safari Font Rendering changes thinner when any Element on the page gets position:fixed;

Tags: css, safari, custom-font

The following problem occurs only on **Safari for OS X**.

My problem is that if I make one `Element` with `position: fixed`, it renders the font smaller than when I don't have that `Element` loaded.

Here's a link to an example of said problem: http://www.noticekom.ch.k1859.ims-firmen.de/home.html

The element is used on 'Home' & 'Agentur'. On both of these sites; the rendering of the text is *smaller* than others. The fixed position is used to make the effect from the last content on the homepage. When I switch it to `position: absolute`; the font renders normally, but the effect obviously is not working.

Does anyone know a workaround for that?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
body { -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased; }
```

This made it :)

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

Answer (score 1):

`Webkit-font-smoothing` didn't work for me. Adding a background to the element to make sure it is fully opaque worked

[Safari changing font weights when unrelated animations are running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733011/safari-changing-font-weights-when-unrelated-animations-are-running)